# Check to make sure a solidity line of code ran successfully

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

how do I confirm this a solidity line of code ran successfully

```
claimed[msg.sender] = claimed[msg.sender].add(1); // make sure this goes first before transfer to prevent reentrancy
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's the [SafeMath](https://github.com/ConsenSysMesh/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol) library function `add()`, it contains an `assert()` condition in case of integer overlow. If the `claimed[msg.sender]` value overflows, it throws an exception, and an uncaught exception causes the transaction to revert.

So if the transaction executing this line doesn't revert (assuming there's no try/catch block), the line was executed successfully.